# bash - re-sort array as if it was a circle by setting a startpoint

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I use this kind of setting in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(C G D A E B)

if [[ "$1" = "--setstart" ]] || [[ "$1" = "-s" ]]; then
    if [ -n "$2" ]; then

        array=($(sed "s/.*$2 /$2 /" <<< "${array[@]}"))

    else
        printf "\nno argument...!\n"
    fi
fi

for a in "${array[@]}"; do
    printf "%s " "$a"
done    
echo
```

the `--setstart` option enables me to select where to start reading the array
(the `sed` command was the the way I could think of at the moment to solve this problem).

The script itself run without option prints: `C G D A E B`
If I set a value with `--setstart` I get the array printed from that point, so `--setstart D` would print: `D A E B`.

How could I introduce an option that would kinda print the `array` as a cycle, so the part cut of in the beginning would be put to its end.
So lets say setting `D` would print: `D A E B C G`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Bash Substring (Subarray) Expansion (i.e. `${parameter:offset:length}`) ...

```
array=(A B C D E F)

start=$1
# handle negative offsets
[[ $start -lt 0 ]] && start=$((${#array[@]} + start))

# the star of the show, create array2 from two sub-arrays of array
array2=("${array[@]:$start}" "${array[@]:0:$start}")

echo "${array2[@]}"
```

Here we're putting  the original array in a newly ordered array just to illustrate. (I've omitted some obvious boundary checking and the like.)

```
$ ./rotate.sh 3
D E F A B C
```

**Update:** I modified the script above to handle negative offsets (inspired by [ikkachu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412501/213782))...

```
$ ./rotate.sh -2
E F A B C D
```

**Update 2:** For the script to instead accept one of the letters "A" through "F", which is more in line with the example in the question, replace `start=$1` with this:

```
# Convert [A-F] to ASCII code then normalize to [0-5]
LC_CTYPE=C start=$(( $(printf %d "'$1") - 65 ))
```

Of course, if you don't have a nicely ordered array of letters than you'd need something more like this which will handle arbitrary array elements:

```
idx=0
for elem in "${array[@]}"; do
    [[ $elem = $1 ]] && break
    ((idx++))
done
start=$idx
```

Comment: Just for completion, substituting the start variable with this `sed` command makes it work like I need it `start=$(sed 's/A/0/g;s/B/1/g;s/C/2/g;s/D/3/g;s/E/4/g;s/F/5/g' <<< "$1")`

Comment: @nath I kinda forgot you were looking for param with an array value rather than an index. I updated my answer with a shortcut for A-F and also general purpose code for any array values.

Comment: **again much thanks to you!** Both updates work pretty nice. I have two further questions: The `LC_CTYPE=C...` solution works quite nice, how do I extend it to use more letters, say `A-Z`? The `idx=0 for...` solution works for all letters but hangs if the letters in the array are followed by a number like: `A1 B2` etc... (I know this is kind of extending the question but I'm really interested... :-)

Comment: ohh sorry, my bad! you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Use modulo. Bash/ksh:

```
$ cat rotate.sh
#!/bin/bash
array=(A B C D E F)
n=${#array[@]}
start=${1-0}
i=0;
while (( i < n )) ; do
    printf "%s " "${array[(start + i) % n]}"
    (( i++ ))
done
echo
```

Zsh starts array indexing from 1, so would need a minor adaptation. The first command line parameter sets the start position `start`, which can be negative:

```
$ ./rotate.sh 2
C D E F A B
```

It should be simple enough to modify that to find the start point by value.

Comment: Much thanks for this snippet. This is really nice, especially since it is accepting negative values. I'll mainly accept the other answer for simplicity reasons since it would just need one extra line.

Comment: I took inspiration from @ikkachu and modified my answer to handle negative offsets as well.